# Two jquery ui tabbed divs on one page. One works, the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jtabbedpane

I have a page with two div panels, a left and a right. Both panels are tabbed using jquery-2.1.4.min.js and jquery-ui.js. One panel has three tabs, and it works.

The js in the head of my page looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    // Doesn't matter if following two lines are reversed. Same output.
    $( "#property-card" ).show().tabs(); // this one doesn't work
    $( "#tabs" ).show().tabs(); // this one works
});
```

The html looks like this:

```
//This tabbed content works:
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tasks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Photos</a></li>
  </ul>  

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <!-- Tasks -->
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
    <!-- Notes -->
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-3">
    <!-- Other -->
  </div>
```

The other div panel looks something like this:

```
//This one shows hyperlinked text within the content area, instead of showing tabs
<div id="property-card" class="eight columns light-manilla curved10 border-dark border-2 border-ridge padding-1-percent">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#property">Property</a></li>
    <li><a href="#property-help">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#property-list-price">List Price</a></li>
    <li><a href="#property-taxes">Taxes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#property-hoa">HOA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#property-showing-instructions">Showing Instructions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#property-bpo-values">BPO Values</a></li>
    <li><a href="#property-buyer-leads">Buyer Leads</a></li>
  </ul>  


    <div id="property">

    </div>

    <div id="property-help">

    </div>

    <div id="property-list-price">

    </div>

    <div id="property-taxes">

    </div>

    <div id="property-hoa">

    </div>

    <div id="property-showing-instructions">

    </div>

    <div id="property-bpo-values">

    </div>

    <div id="property-buyer-leads">

    </div>

</div>
```

(not sure if this is related) Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:14346
ReferenceError: data is not defined
(I think this one is related) jquery-2.1.4.min.js%20line%202%20%3E%20eval:35:1

See inline screen shot sample for example of what's going on.

[image]

Comment: where is the tab contents for the left side tabs ? can you provide the complete code. May be a Fiddle as well if you can

Comment: First of all; the xhr error is most probably not related (although it could stop further execution). But my guess is that it's merely a css problem. Is the markup linked to `#tabs` _and_ `#property-card`?

Comment: can you just test removing - `class="eight columns light-manilla curved10 border-dark border-2 border-ridge padding-1-percent"` & let me know the result. I don't see anything fishy except that

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Hi Nikhil, I just removed the entire class attribute from the problem div, and the output is exactly the same (but without the custom styling).

Comment: @giorgio I pretty much cloned the working div, and then just renamed the ids and the tab references to the ids. Everything seems to match up to the working div. One more thing I guess I'll try, and that's to remove the rather large chunk of content from the non-working div.

Comment: @TARKUS - You have included the `jqueryUI.css` ? I have replicated your code, there seems to no problem. Can you [check here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/wzzmbd).

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa found it. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hate answering my own questions, but in another file at the bottom of my html, there is another javascript block, which "activated" the working tabbed div, but because I didn't add the new tabbed div (because I didn't realize that second javascript block was there) the second tabbed div didn't work. Here is what made it work:

```
$(function () {
    $('#property-card').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var $activeTab1 = $('#property-card').tabs('option', 'active');
        }
    });
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var $activeTab2 = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
            if ($activeTab2 == 2) {
                // HERE YOU CAN ADD CODE TO RUN WHEN THE SECOND TAB HAS BEEN CLICKED
                $("#mls-images-carousel").css("display","block");
                retrieveAssetImages('<?php echo $as_id; ?>');
            }
            else{
                $("#mls-images-carousel").css("display","hidden");
            }
        }
    });
});
```